# Get variable value from Logarithm?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, arithmetic

I have below equation.

$$ x =  \left(\frac{1}{-2 \log_{10}\left(9 + \frac{46}{x}\right)}\right)^2 $$

I am not very familiar with Logarithm.

How can I grab value of $x$ from this equation?

Comment: Is it $$x = \left(\frac{1}{-2 \log_{10}\left(9 + \frac{46}{x}\right)}\right)^2$$

Comment: Yes,
That's my equation.

Comment: Are the two $x$:s in the equation the same?

Comment: Yes,
They are same.

Comment: In that case, I would say it's next to impossible to completely solve for $x$. Mixing transcendental functions results in many difficulties ...

Comment: Yes,
That's why i asked question here.
Hope i'll find solution for it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks @GNUSupporter I'll study it & follow it for next time for sure.

Comment: To find the code quickly, you may consider [an online editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: Okay, Thanks again met

Comment: An approximate solution to the equation is $x \approx 0.022886$.

Comment: Dear @MattiP. I want formula. How i can solve it. Like how i will get value from this equation? Which operation should i follow?

Comment: I'm afraid it's simply not possible. You can write the equation to the form
$$
4x\log^2{\left( 9 + \frac{46}{x} \right)} =1
$$
But there is no algebraic method to exactly solve this.

Comment: What you think about @user 108128 Answer?

Comment: As Matti P told, you will need numerical methods for this one. Like sandwiching the solution into a smaller and smaller interval, or possibly iterative methods. user108128 didn't really give you anything useful IMO.

Comment: You may obtain the numerical value proposed by Matti using the iterations $\;\displaystyle x_{n+1}=\left(\frac{1}{-2 \log_{10}\left(9 + \frac{46}{x_n}\right)}\right)^2,\;x_0=1$

Comment: Just do it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+4(lg(9%2B46%2Fx))%5E2+*+x+%3D+1

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = \dfrac1{9y^2},$ then
$$3y = 2\log_{10}(9(1+46y^2)).\tag1$$
If $y=2,$ then $RHS\approx6.44\approx LHS.$

So

$\log_{10}(9(185+46(y^2-4))) = \log_{10}1665 + \log_{10}\left(1+\dfrac{46}{285}(y^2-4)\right) =\dfrac1{\ln10}\left(\ln1665+\ln\left(1+\dfrac{46}{285}(y^2-4)\right)\right)\approx\dfrac1{\ln10}\left(\ln1665+\dfrac{46}{285}(y^2-4)\right),$

and this allows to obtain $y$ approximately from the quadratic equation
$$y^2-2ay + b = 0,$$
where
$$a = \dfrac{855}{184}\ln10\approx 10.700,\quad b = \dfrac{285}{46}\ln1665 - 4 \approx 41.957.$$
Therefore,
$$y= a +\sqrt{a^2-c} \approx2.1833,$$
$$\boxed{x\approx0.0233}.\tag2$$

On the another hand, the issue equality allows to apply iteration method for the calculation of the root with the arbitrary precision.

Using $(2)$ as initial approximation, easy to get:
$$x_0 = 0.0233,\quad x_1 \approx 0.0229934,\quad x_2 \approx 0.0229137,\quad x_3 \approx 0.0228929,\quad x_4\approx 0.228874,\quad x_5 \approx 0.228860, \quad x_6\approx 0.228857\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an analytical answer other than observing that it will be true at x=0 as the Log term will tend to infinity as x tends to 0.

Numerically it's straightforward and even Excel using GoalSeek can give you the value x = 0.023 (3 s.f.). That's solving:

$$ x -  \left(\frac{1 }{-2 \log_{10}\left( 9 + \frac{46}{x }\right)}\right)^2 = 0$$

You can easily see that for x greater than this value (x > 0.023):

$$ x >  \left(\frac{1 }{-2 \log_{10}\left( 9 + \frac{46}{x }\right)}\right)^2$$
since

$$ \left(\frac{1 }{-2 \log_{10}\left( 9 + \frac{46}{x }\right)}\right)^2 \to  \left(\frac{1 }{-2 \log_{10}( 9 )}\right)^2 \text{ as } x\to\infty $$

[Sorry for the formatting]

You could prove this more completely by showing that the gradient of the right hand side is always less than 1 when x > 0.023 .

Presuming x has to be a real number, the equation is undefined between x = -46/9 and x = 0. Anyway, the right hand side of your equation can't be negative for real x.

Comment: A better numerical method that 'GoalSeek in Excel' would be Newton-Raphson or Interval Bisection. N-R has the benefit of needing the derivative function that you'll work out to show the gradient of your RHS is always less than 1 when x > 0.023.

Comment: \to for tends to, \log for log, \text{} for text

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$ write the equation
$$x = \left(\frac{1}{-2 \log_{10}\left(9 + \frac{46}{x}\right)}\right)^2$$
as
$$\dfrac{1}{-2\sqrt{x}}=\log_{10}\left(9 + \frac{46}{x}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\ln10}\ln\left(9 + \frac{46}{x}\right)$$
or
$$\dfrac{\ln10}{-2\sqrt{x}}=\ln\left(9 + \frac{46}{x}\right)=\ln9+\ln\left(1 + \frac{46}{9x}\right)$$
An approximation could be find with the series
$$\ln(1+z)=z-\dfrac{1}{2}z^2+\dfrac{1}{3}z^3-\dfrac{1}{4}z^4+\dfrac{1}{5}z^5+\cdots$$
by getting some terms!

Comment: It'll be more complex.
cause z is unknown value :(

Comment: @SharmaVishal, $z = 46/9x$.

Answer (score 0):

$x\log^2(9+\frac{46}{x})=\frac{1}{4}$

$[\sqrt x\log(9+\frac{46}{x})]^2=[\log(9+\frac{46}{x})^{\sqrt x}]^2=\frac{1}{4}$

$\log (9+\frac{46}{x})^\sqrt x=±\frac{1}{2}$

$(9+\frac{46}{x})^\sqrt x= 10^{±\frac{1}{2}}$

$(9+\frac{46}{x})^\sqrt x= 10^{+\frac{1}{2}}=3.162..$

$(9+\frac{46}{x})^\sqrt x= 10^{-\frac{1}{2}}=0.316$

Now by try and error you can find the solution.